# error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed ubuntu 20.4

Tags: grub2

i have upgraded ubuntu 18.4.4 to 20.4 but i'am wrong to located the grub into /boot/efi partition i can't change it

`sudo apt-get upgrade
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    Calculating upgrade... Done
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    1 not fully installed or removed.
    After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
    Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.142+2.04-1ubuntu26) ...
    mount: /var/lib/grub/esp: /dev/sdb already mounted or mount point busy.
    dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
     installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 32[image]
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     grub-efi-amd64-signed
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

can help me to fix this ?

the picture not want to disable /boot/efi when i choose grub install device

Comment: I'm having the same issue. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296838/grub-install-error-failed-to-register-the-efi-boot-entry-operation-not-permitt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try purging grub and reinstall. Worked for me!

```
sudo apt-get purge grub\*
sudo apt-get install grub-efi
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo update-grub
```